# Meteor - Access and Display Images

Tags: javascript, meteor, collectionfs

How would you access a folder full of images, get the url for each image and put it in an array, then {{each}} over that array to display each image on a page of my choosing?  Everyone keeps saying CollectionFS, but for some reason, when I set it up:

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem('images', {
    path: '~/category/engagements'
});

Images = new FS.Collection('images', {
    stores: [imageStore]
});
```

I can access Images in the console, but the array is empty. Isn't this all I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

CollectionFS keeps a mongo collection that essentially points to images that have been stored in a file system somewhere, either on the server's disk or in the cloud. afaik, you can't simply point CollectionFS at a directory full of files, you need to put the files there using CollectionFS in the first place with (in your case) `Images.insert()`

Answer (score 0):

I've found your question very interesting so I've started to think about a way. I'm pretty new to Meteor and Node.js so I imagine that someone with much better understanding can come up with a better solution but my basic idea is to import every image from a directory to a CollectionFS.

Here is what I came up with (**beware, this is a 10 minute mock-up not a copy-paste solution!**)

```
var basedir = '../../../../../public/';

var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {
  path: basedir
});

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [imageStore]
});


if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Images.allow({
    'insert': function () {
      return true;
    },
    'download' : function(){
      return true;
    }
  });  

  function importFiles(importDir) {
    var dir = basedir + importDir;
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    _(files).each(function(f){
      fs.readFile(dir + f, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var newFile = new FS.File();

        newFile.attachData(data, {type: 'image/png'});
        newFile.name(f);
        var insertedFile = Images.insert(newFile,function(err,fob){
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Uploaded successfully');
        });
      }));
    })
  }

 importFiles('import/'); // this dir in under my public folder

}
```

This code imports everything from public/import to the directory specified for the `imageStore`.
Be careful though, this can cause serious memory issues because it's reading the whole file with `fs.readFile`

You need to install the Node.js fs library `meteor add peerlibrary:fs`

Don't forget to filter the file list and set the correct MIME type based on the extension for example.

After you have imported the images you can use CollectionFS ``` find()`` to list the images and then ```fileObject.url()``` to display them.

There are examples on CollectionFS GitHub page e.g.:
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/#url